# list of Directorys,files using Python Script 

Tags: python

I need list of all files inside the current directory and subdirectories along with their file and directory permissions in Ubuntu OS,How to do it?using python programming.

Thanks in Advance
Mukthayr

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: Use the REPL to learn about your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk()` returns a generator that returns tuples, and each entry yielded by the generator is immediately expanded, in a similar way to in the following code:

```
>>> tuple = (1,2,3)
>>> one,two,three = tuple
>>> print one,two,three
1 2 3
```

Then:

```
>>> list = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> for a,b in list:
...   print a, b
... 
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: To be precise, `os.walk` returns a generator, not a list.